# How to get specific column value from .csv Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a .csv file with Bitcoin price and market data, and I want to get the 5th and 7th columns from the last row in the file. I have worked out how to get the last row, but I'm not sure how to extract columns (values) 5 and 7 from it. Code:

```
with open('BTCAUD_data.csv', mode='r') as BTCAUD_data:
    writer = csv.reader(BTCAUD_data, delimiter=',')
    data = list(BTCAUD_data)[-1]
    print(data)
```

Edit: How would I also add column names, and would adding them help me? (I have already manually put the names into individual columns in the first line of the file itself)

Edit #2: Forget about the column names, they are unimportant. I still don't have a working solution. I have a vague idea that I'm not actually reading the file as a list, but rather as a string. (This means when I subscript the `data` variable, I get a single digit, rather than an item in a list) Any hints to how I read the line as a list?

Edit #3: I have got everything working to expectations now, thanks for everyone's help :)

Comment: Can you show me the names of the column you put at the first line?

Comment: @deecue ```Raw Price Change, Price Change Percent, Weighted Average, Last Price, Last Qty, Bid Price, Bid Qty, Ask Price, Ask Qty, Open Price, High Price, Low Price, Trading Volume, Quote Volume
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never uses the csv-reader. You can do so like this:

```
import csv

# This creates a file with demo data
with open('BTCAUD_data.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join( f"header{u}" for u in range(10))+"\n")
    for l in range(20):
        f.write(','.join( f"line{l}_{c}" for c in range(10))+"\n")


# this reads and processes the demo data
with open('BTCAUD_data.csv', 'r', newline="") as BTCAUD_data:
    reader = csv.reader(BTCAUD_data, delimiter=',')
    # 1st line is header
    header =  next(reader)
    # skip through the file, row will be the last line read
    for row in reader:
        pass

print(header)
print(row)

#  each row is a list  and you can index into it
print(header[4], header[7])
print(row[4], row[7])
```

Output:

```
['header0', 'header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4', 'header5', 'header6', 'header7', 'header8', 'header9']
['line19', 'line19', 'line19', 'line19', 'line19', 'line19', 'line19', 'line19', 'line19', 'line19']
header4 header7
line19_4 line19_7
```

Comment: Ok thanks heaps for your help! Just out of curiosity, how would I go about ea if I didn't want to have named columns, and just get the output (I'm still trying to get my head around reading/writing from files!)

Comment: @proton You do not have named colums with the default csv.reader - you get a list per row in your file and index into it by index ( 4 and 7 here). I don't quite get what you are asking in your comment.

Comment: Sorry I'm just really confused by all this (mainly the first ```with open``` section) I will have a deeper look into the code and try and understand it.

Comment: @proton - the first with open(..) creates the file , the second part reads it back in and processes it. You did not provide how your data looks like, so I created sample data myself

Comment: ohhh ok! Thanks for clarifying, makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Better use pandas for handling CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('filename')
```

`df.column_name`  will give the corresponding column
[image]

If you read this csv file into df and try `df.Year` will give you the Year column.

Comment: Pandas has a big learning curve - if it is a tool you know thats ok, for geting 2 values of the **last row** the csv module is more then adequat and takes less efford.

Comment: The pandas option seems easier to me, 14 lines versus 3....